# How can i make text in header Smaller when user scroll down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have fixed header with one bigger text. I would like the text to get smaller when someone scrolls down and returns to its size when the scroll is at the top.

CSS applied when scroll go down should be:

```
font-size: 15px;     
padding-left: 15%;
top: 10px;
```

[Here you can see where i want that text to move(how does it look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr3oF.png)

My HTML:

```html
<div class="bignadpis">
    <p>Účtovníctvo a zúčtovanie <br> zdravotnej starostlivosti Svit</p>
</div>
```

and CSS for it

```css
.bignadpis {
  z-index: 10001;
  font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5% 
}
```

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be the result you are looking for.

By manipulating the `quantity` value, you can determine yourself when it reaches "`15px`".

```js
var scrollCn = function(quantity)
{
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset || document.scrollTop)  - (document.clientTop || 0);
  
  var size = 30 - ((scrollTop / quantity) || 0);
  
  if(size <= 15) size = 15;
  
  document.querySelector('.bignadpis p').setAttribute('style', 'font-size: '+size+'px;');


};
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ scrollCn(10) });
```

```css
.bignadpis {
z-index: 10001;
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: fixed;
float: left;
padding-left: 5% }

html
{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bignadpis">
        <p>Účtovníctvo a zúčtovanie <br> zdravotnej starostlivosti Svit</p>
    </div>
```

**For your second question**

```js
var scrollCn = function(quantity)
{
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset || document.scrollTop)  - (document.clientTop || 0);
  
  var size = 30 - ((scrollTop / quantity) || 0);
  
  if(size <= 15) size = 15;
  
  document.querySelector('.bignadpis p').setAttribute('style', 'font-size: '+size+'px;');


};
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ scrollCn(10) });
```

```css
.bignadpis {
max-width: 400px;
z-index: 10001;
font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: fixed;
float: left;
padding-left: 5% }

html
{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bignadpis">
        <p>Účtovníctvo a zúčtovanie zdravotnej starostlivosti Svit - And more string you want!</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but i will need bit more help, current status is that it is working, but i will need to add there something. when i use "<br>" in that "<p>" and it will be scrolled and smaller, it doesnt fit to the header. so i need to make it broken when i am on top and full line when i scroll, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: For this, you must specify a "`max-width`" value in the "`.bignadpis`" class. You must also remove "`<br />`". I'm adding a new example.

Comment: Thank you very very very much :) all working just fine

Answer (score 2):

You can play around with this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #header {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 50px 10px;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 90px;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">Header text</div>

  <div style="margin-top:200px;padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px">
    <p>This is an example of shrinking text.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    // When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the document, resize the header's font size. You can modidy this.
    window.onscroll = function() {
      scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "30px";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "90px";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It should give you the basic idea about resizing text on scroll.