# Something like media query for Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, header

Recently I was asking this [question about resizing header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624094/how-can-i-make-text-in-header-smaller-when-user-scroll-down/64624292?noredirect=1#comment114270081_64624292) and someone gave me a JavaScript which is working great, until it comes to resizing and using media query, when I scroll up (with smaller screen size and that mean with smaller default font-size) javascript change font-size back to the default size.

Here is my code (doesnt work for some reason here but in my code it does)

Question is : how can i change this Java script to somehow make him responsive ?

```js
    var scrollCn = function(quantity)
{
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset || document.scrollTop)  - (document.clientTop || 0);
  
  var size = 25 - ((scrollTop / quantity) || 0);
  if(size <= 15) size = 15;

/*   var size = 20 - ((scrollTop / quantity) || 0);
  if(size <= 10) size = 10; 
  
  Something i have tried-not working :D 
  */ 
  
  document.querySelector('.bignadpis p').setAttribute('style', 'font-size: '+size+'px;');

};
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ scrollCn(10) });
```

```css
body {
    height: 3000px;
}

.bignadpis {
    max-width: 500px;
    z-index: 10001;
    font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1400px) {
    .bignadpis {
        max-width: 400px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bignadpis">
           <p>Účtovníctvo a zúčtovanie zdravotnej starostlivosti Svit</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: add your media queries to the code.

Comment: I did @sergeykuznetsov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit. Added a condition for the width of the browser window. It works like a media query. Was it necessary?

```
if( window.innerWidth <= 1400 ){
      var size = 20 - ((scrollTop / quantity) || 0);
      if(size <= 10) size = 10; 
}
```

```js
var scrollCn = function(quantity)
{
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset || document.scrollTop)  - (document.clientTop || 0);
  
   if( window.innerWidth > 1400 ){
      var size = 25 - ((scrollTop / quantity) || 0);
      if(size <= 15) size = 15;
    } 
  
   if( window.innerWidth <= 1400 ){
      var size = 20 - ((scrollTop / quantity) || 0);
      if(size <= 10) size = 10; 
    } 
  
  document.querySelector('.bignadpis p').setAttribute('style', 'font-size: '+size+'px;');

};
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ scrollCn(10) });
```

```css
body {
    height: 3000px;
}

.bignadpis {
    max-width: 500px;
    z-index: 10001;
    font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:1400px) {
    .bignadpis {
        max-width: 400px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bignadpis">
           <p>Účtovníctvo a zúčtovanie zdravotnej starostlivosti Svit</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great, i thought it will be something like this, but i am new at js <3

Comment: The fact is that using a media query css cannot be solved in your task, because the dynamic change of the font size. And note that I also wrapped the logic for 25 pixels in a condition. It will be so right. Happy to help.